# Safari on Mac and IOS 14 Won't Play HTML 5 MP4 Video

Tags: ios, node.js, ffmpeg, symfony4, mp4

So i have developed a chat application that uses node for the back-end. When a user selects a video on their iphone it usually is .mov format so when it's sent to the node server it's then converted to mp4 with ffmpeg. All that works fine, then if i load up my chat again in Chrome on my mac the video plays just fine as the mp4.

[image]

This screenshot shows the video embed is there, set to mp4 yet it won't play in Safari on my mac or my phone, in fact it just shows the video as 0 seconds long yet i can play it in chrome and also download the mp4 file by accessing the embed url directly.

Any ideas? I had it convert to mp4 to prevent things like this, but safari doesn't seem to even like mp4 files.

The back-end part that serves the private file is in Symfony 4 (PHP):

```
/**
     * @Route("/private/files/download/{base64Path}", name="downloadFile")
     * @param string $base64Path
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function downloadFile(string $base64Path, Request $request) : Response
    {


        // get token
        if(!$token = $request->query->get('token')){
            return new Response('Access Denied',403);
        }



        /** @var UserRepository $userRepo */
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);

        /** @var User $user */
        if(!$user = $userRepo->findOneBy(['deleted'=>false,'active'=>true,'systemUser'=>false,'apiKey'=>$token])){
            return new Response('Access Denied',403);
        }



        // get path
        if($path = base64_decode($base64Path)){

            // make sure the folder we need exists
            $fullPath = $this->getParameter('private_upload_folder') . '/' . $path;



            if(!file_exists($fullPath)){
                return new Response('File Not Found',404);
            }

        

            $response = new Response();
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', mime_content_type($fullPath));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . basename($fullPath) . '"');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($fullPath));
            $response->headers->set('Pragma', "no-cache");
            $response->headers->set('Expires', "0");
            $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "binary");

            $response->sendHeaders();

            $response->setContent(readfile($fullPath));

            return $response;
        }

        return new Response('Invalid Path',404);
    }
```

This works fine everywhere except safari when trying to embed the video. It's done like this because the videos are not public and need an access token.

UPDATE: Here is a test link of an mp4, you'll have to allow the insecure certificate as it's on a quick test sub domain. If you open it in chrome, you'll see a 3 second video of my 3d printer curing station, if you load the same link in safari, you'll see it doesn't work

https://tester.nibbrstaging.com/private/files/download/Y2hhdC83Nzk1Y2U2MC04MDFmLTExZWItYjkzYy1lZjI4ZGYwMDhkOTMubXA0?token=6ab1720bfe922d44208c25f655d61032

The server runs on cPanel with Apache and i think it might be something to do with the video needs streaming?

**UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS IN SAFARI BUT NOW BROKEN IN CHROME:**

Chrome is now giving Content-Length: 0 but it's working fine in safari.

```
public function downloadFile(string $base64Path, Request $request) : ?Response
    {

        ob_clean();

        // get token
        if(!$token = $request->query->get('token')){
            return new Response('Access Denied',403);
        }


        

        /** @var UserRepository $userRepo */
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);

        /** @var User $user */
        if(!$user = $userRepo->findOneBy(['deleted'=>false,'active'=>true,'systemUser'=>false,'apiKey'=>$token])){
            return new Response('Access Denied',403);
        }



        // get path
        if($path = base64_decode($base64Path)){

            // make sure the folder we need exists
            $fullPath = $this->getParameter('private_upload_folder') . '/' . $path;



            if(!file_exists($fullPath)){
                return new Response('File Not Found',404);
            }


            $filesize = filesize($fullPath);
            $mime = mime_content_type($fullPath);

            header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){

                // Parse the range header to get the byte offset
                $ranges = array_map(
                    'intval', // Parse the parts into integer
                    explode(
                        '-', // The range separator
                        substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 6) // Skip the `bytes=` part of the header
                    )
                );



                // If the last range param is empty, it means the EOF (End of File)
                if(!$ranges[1]){
                    $ranges[1] = $filesize - 1;
                }

                header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                header('Content-Length: ' . ($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])); // The size of the range

                // Send the ranges we offered
                header(
                    sprintf(
                        'Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d', // The header format
                        $ranges[0], // The start range
                        $ranges[1], // The end range
                        $filesize // Total size of the file
                    )
                );

                // It's time to output the file
                $f = fopen($fullPath, 'rb'); // Open the file in binary mode
                $chunkSize = 8192; // The size of each chunk to output

                // Seek to the requested start range
                fseek($f, $ranges[0]);

                // Start outputting the data
                while(true){
                    // Check if we have outputted all the data requested
                    if(ftell($f) >= $ranges[1]){
                        break;
                    }

                    // Output the data
                    echo fread($f, $chunkSize);

                    // Flush the buffer immediately
                    @ob_flush();
                    flush();
                }
            }else{

                // It's not a range request, output the file anyway
                header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);

                // Read the file
                @readfile($filesize);

                // and flush the buffer
                @ob_flush();
                flush();



            }

        }else {

            return new Response('Invalid Path', 404);
        }
    }
```

I have notice in chrome that it's sending the range header like this:

Range: bytes=611609-

Where safari sends

Range: bytes=611609-61160

So for some reason chrome is missing the second range amount, that obviously means my code can't find a range number for the second one.

Doesn’t matter what I do I can’t get it working in both chrome and safari. Safari wants the byte range part , chrome seems to request it then sends a new request for the full file but even the full file part of the code gives a 500 error. If I take out the byte range bit then it works fine in chrome but not safari.

**UPDATE:**

Here is some strange things going on in chrome:

For the video i am testing with it makes 3 range requests:

REQUEST 1 HEADERS - asking for bytes 0- (to the end of the file)

```
GET /private/files/download/Y2hhdC83Nzk1Y2U2MC04MDFmLTExZWItYjkzYy1lZjI4ZGYwMDhkOTMubXA0?token=6ab1720bfe922d44208c25f655d61032 HTTP/1.1

Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Referer: https://gofollow.vip/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=0-
```

RESPONSE GIVES IT BACK ALL THE BYTES IN THE FILE AS THAT'S WHAT WAS ASKED FOR BY CHROME:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 12:35:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 611609
Content-Range: bytes 0-611609/611610
Vary: User-Agent
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

SECOND REQUEST HEADERS: NOW IT'S ASKING FOR 589824 to the end of the file:

```
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Referer: https://gofollow.vip/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=589824-
```

RESPONSE OBLIGES:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 12:35:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 21785
Content-Range: bytes 589824-611609/611610
Vary: User-Agent
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

THEN IT'S MAKING THIS 3rd REQUEST THAT GIVES AN INTERNAL SERVER ERORR, THIS TIME IT'S LITERALLY ASKING FOR THE LAST BYTE:

```
GET /private/files/download/Y2hhdC83Nzk1Y2U2MC04MDFmLTExZWItYjkzYy1lZjI4ZGYwMDhkOTMubXA0?token=6ab1720bfe922d44208c25f655d61032 HTTP/1.1

Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Referer: https://gofollow.vip/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=611609-
```

RESPONSE - THE CONTENT LENGTH IS 0 BECAUSE THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE REQUESTED BYTES AND THE BYTES RETURNED:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 12:35:56 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: origin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Expires: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 12:35:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes 611609-611609/611610
Vary: User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: We need to see an example mp4.

Comment: @szatmary i have updated the question

Comment: File looks Ok. I'm guessing you dont have range requests handled correctly on the server. You need to add support for partial content/

Comment: Yeh I was thinking it needs streaming over doesn’t it?

Comment: No, Not streaming. Range requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: Ok that is kinda streaming though isn’t it, sending a chunk at a time

Comment: No, Because you are not "sending one chunk at a time". The client is requesting one chunk at a time, and the server is just responding to them. Requests can be out of order, multiple requests can be made in parallel, and you can use a range on any file type, not just video. A client can "stream" without range requests if you had created this video with "fast start". That is called "progressive download". Or the client can use range to read the files headers at the end (because you didn't use fast start). That is called "pseudo streaming".

Comment: @szatmary I have updated my question with new code. This is now workig in safari and loads the video - but now it stopped working in chrome with a generic internal server error. It comes back with Content-Length: 0 in chrome for some reason.

Comment: @szatmary updated again, i've noticed in chrome the request is doing Range: bytes=611609- Where safari sends Range: bytes=611609-61160 .Why is crhome missing the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that i finally found the issue. it was asking for the last byte in the third request and the following code to work out the size of the content sending back:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . ($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])); // The size of the range
```

Was producing the length as 0 as the last byte until the end of the file works out to 0. So i changed it to plus 1 to the end:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . (($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])+1)); // The size of the range
```

I thought i may have issues with this, but turns out it works in both browsers